# MySQL innoDB: Long time of query execution

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, innodb

I'm having troubles to run this SQL:

[image]

I think it's a `index problem` but I don't know because I dind't make this database and I'm just a simple programmer.

The problem is, that table has 64260 records, so that query gets crazy when executing, I have to stop mysql and run again because the computer get frozen.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `value_magnitudes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `magnitude_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdi_belongs_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reading_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1118402 ;
```

#### Query

```
select * from value_magnitudes
where id in 
(
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM value_magnitudes
    WHERE magnitude_id = 234
    and date(reading_date) >= '2013-04-01'
    group by date(reading_date)
)
```

**EDIT2**

[image]

Comment: So, What is your Question?

Comment: I need to improve that table, in order to make that query quickly, I don't know how or what to index, because the picture says lot of null and they're not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add an index on `(magnitude_id, reading_date)`:

```
ALTER TABLE
  ADD INDEX magnitude_id__reading_date__IX       -- just a name for the index
    (magnitude_id, reading_date) ;
```

Then try this variation:

```
SELECT vm.* 
FROM value_magnitudes AS vm
  JOIN 
  ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id
    FROM value_magnitudes
    WHERE magnitude_id = 234
      AND reading_date >= '2013-04-01'         -- changed so index is used
    GROUP BY DATE(reading_date)
  ) AS vi
    ON vi.id = vm.id ;
```

The `GROUP BY DATE(reading_date)` will still need to apply the function to all the selected (thorugh the index) rows and that cannot be improved, unless you follow @jurgen's advice and split the column into `date` and `time` columns.

Comment: So, was it helpful? How is the execution time now?

Comment: You edited it but, the first edition was executed in 0,005 secs so it is amazing @ypercube don't know why it is so fast, because I didn't indexed to try if it was the problem, and it run so gooood =)

Comment: My edit did not change the code. I only added comments and the last paragraph. Good to hear that it's running fast now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to get results for every day you need to extract the date from a datetime column with the function `date()`. That makes indexes useless.

You can split up the `reading_date` column into `reading_date` and `reading_time`. Then you can run the query without a function and indexes will work.

Additionally you can change the query into a `join`

```
select * 
from value_magnitudes v
inner join 
(
    SELECT min(id) as id
    FROM value_magnitudes
    WHERE magnitude_id = 234
    and reading_date >= '2013-04-01'
    group by reading_date
) x on x.id = v.id
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would change your query to:

```
select * from value_magnitudes where id = (
  select min(id) from value_magnitudes
  where magnitude_id = 234
  and DATE(reading_date) >= '2013-04-01' 
)
```

You don't need to use the IN clause when the subquery is only going to return one record.

Then, I would make sure you have an index on magnitude_id and reading_date (probably a two field index) as that's what you are querying against in the subquery. Without that index, you are scanning the table each time.

Also if possible change magnitude_id and reading_date to non null. Null values and indexes are not great fits.

Comment: There is a `group by` in the query. So no single record from the subquery

Comment: I want your help adding the index =)

Comment: Check out @ypercube's answer as he supplied the table alter for adding the index