# SQL: How to select multiple records per day, assuming that each day contain more than 1 value, MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have a huge table which contains multiple records from each day. I would like to get like any 5 or 10 records from everyday. Each row has created_at field, timestamp format example: 2015-01-01 00:00:01. And every row has a unique ID field.

Using MySQL 5.5.44

I found this ([SQL: How to select one record per day...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480228/sql-how-to-select-one-record-per-day-assuming-that-each-day-contain-more-than/16480254#16480254?newreg=8dd6029bc40e41d389517e638ed569ee)):

```
select * from value_magnitudes
where id in 
(
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM value_magnitudes
    WHERE magnitude_id = 234
    and date(reading_date) >= '2013-04-01'
    group by date(reading_date)
)
```

It gives me one record from each day. I tried several times to modify that for my needs but I guess it can't be done with that simple query.

Then I found this ([How to select more than 1 record per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410315/how-to-select-more-than-1-record-per-day)):

```
SELECT date_time, other_column
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date_time::date) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  date_time >= '2012-11-01 0:0'
   AND    date_time <  '2012-12-01 0:0'
   ) x
WHERE  rn < 4;
```

Can't get this one working (changed the name of the field of course). It gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY created_at::date) AS rn
>      FROM   tbl
>      WHERE  created_at >= '201' at line 3

So could you guys and gals point me to the right direction, please.

Update:
Desired result would look something like this (only two from same date, but you get the idea):

```
id                                      company_id                          created_at
0001c73d-8f95-49b8-a380-275c3863974d    90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa457d    2015-12-01 22:36:20
000074d3-0116-4d13-bea9-7256d522ea88    53171f70-7b65-4e17-a222-8d9952351b88    2015-12-01 14:09:19
00002a24-c14a-4584-8657-ad62a62d8bb2    ad83edbc-fe82-443f-96fb-8188b91fdd62    2015-12-02 09:15:22
000023b7-9a32-4ac9-9f8d-e18712c0a940    3713bc34-bffa-458d-98bc-266acfcacc6c    2015-12-02 14:57:24
0000d51e-dea7-446c-9974-4536501d77ec    23d1556c-0719-4260-9740-a8882badf2db    2015-12-03 13:19:22
0020e450-866f-4467-b5fe-892d1b9565a0    90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa677d    2015-12-03 13:46:01
00001bc4-6d39-494c-8b4c-43050ebe537e    90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa478d    2015-12-04 22:09:50
000035cf-409f-4cfb-adcd-412eb5def840    90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa434d    2015-12-04 22:50:43
```

INSERT for that would be like:

```
INSERT INTO `invoices` (`id`, `company_id`, `created_at`)
VALUES
    ('0001c73d-8f95-49b8-a380-275c3863974d', '90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa457d', '2015-12-01 22:36:20'),
    ('000074d3-0116-4d13-bea9-7256d522ea88', '53171f70-7b65-4e17-a222-8d9952351b88', '2015-12-01 14:09:19'),
    ('00002a24-c14a-4584-8657-ad62a62d8bb2', 'ad83edbc-fe82-443f-96fb-8188b91fdd62', '2015-12-02 09:15:22'),
    ('000023b7-9a32-4ac9-9f8d-e18712c0a940', '3713bc34-bffa-458d-98bc-266acfcacc6c', '2015-12-02 14:57:24'),
    ('0000d51e-dea7-446c-9974-4536501d77ec', '23d1556c-0719-4260-9740-a8882badf2db', '2015-12-03 13:19:22'),
    ('0020e450-866f-4467-b5fe-892d1b9565a0', '90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa677d', '2015-12-03 13:46:01'),
    ('00001bc4-6d39-494c-8b4c-43050ebe537e', '90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa478d', '2015-12-04 22:09:50'),
    ('000035cf-409f-4cfb-adcd-412eb5def840', '90f87a37-801f-4f05-b86d-b25574aa434d', '2015-12-04 22:50:43');
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Updated desired result and insert for that. Hope people get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable, to get resultset rownumbers since mysql doesn't support *ROWNUM* as oracle.
Please try this :

```
select * 
from (
    select id,date(date_time) as date_time,other_columns,
    case when @date = date(date_time) then 
        @rn := @rn + 1 
    else 
        @rn := 1 
    end as x, -- row numbers for each date_time
    @date := date(date_time)
    from your_table
    inner join(select @date := '', @rn:=1) as tmp
    order by date(date_time) asc
) as tbl
where x <= 5 --5 records for each date_time
```

The query above will give you 5 records (*if any*) for each day.

Comment: I guess this could work but I'm working on a read only slave so I can' write tmp.

Comment: @Taapsa Sorry, what do you mean with *I'm working on a read only slave so I can't write tmp*

Comment: When I run that query I get error: Error writing file '/tmp/MYhvHybc' (Errcode: 28)

Comment: Or what I'm doing wrong here. I changed the date_time to match my table = created_at and I assume that I can give desired timespan in here: " inner join(select @date := ' ' ''?

Comment: @Taapsa No, @date is variable, you can't give desired timespan there. you can add *where clause* in the subquery `...) as tmp where create_at between :from and :to order by date(date_time)...`

Comment: Of course, silly me... After I added that where clause it is working like a charm, thanks a lot!